# pci_iomap: query

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory-mapping

So i am currently mapping the DoorBell area in my card using ioremap_no_cache(), and only 4K size of it. However (unintentionally) i now realise that i am able to ring doorbells /write to locations after this 4K region as well and the strange thing is it seems to work.
I want to know how/why is it working and if possible through this understand in depth of how ioremap_no_cache() actually works under the hood? Code reading and man page only helped so much.
Note that this extra 4K region outside the first 4k region is not there by default

Comment: (1)Is there any other mapping beside the one setup by ioremap_no_cache()? (2) If ioremap_no_cache() only map 4KB size, and the next 4KB is not mapping in kernel space, the access to unmapped area will cause the kernel crash. So I doubt there is other mapping setup already.

Comment: No , it is a pci_iomap(pdev, Doorbell_BAR_Offset, 0); call

Comment: How about the PCI host controller Outbound mapping? The Outbound mapping can translate the system bus address into pci address

Comment: The PCI outbound mapping is not related to MMU, it's related to address routing among peripheral modules.

Comment: @tian, No , it is a pci_iomap(pdev, Doorbell_BAR_Offset, 0);  So i'm wondering if the 0 causes more of the region to be mapped ?

Comment: Hi, smam: since you use pci_iomap(). And to get the length of the Doorbell_BAR, pci_iomap() calls pci_resource_len(). And it means that the length of this BAR is auto-detected during pci scan procedure. And the value will reflect the real size of chip. Are you sure the real size of the BAR is 4KB?

Comment: No, it's okey that the maxlen is 0. It will use pci_resource_len() to get the real length of the BAR.

Comment: You know how pci rescan to get the real length of various BARs? It will write 0xFFFFFFFF to BAR register, then read it back. The value that read back is the real length of the BAR.

Comment: Yes, my guess as well yours was right :) . I printed the pci_resource_len() before calling the pci_iomap and indeed it was a large value - 4194304 i.e 4MB. That explains why/how it is workingm otherwise like you even i first expected that it would crash... Still did not understand your comments re: PCI host controller Outbound mapping though? Could you pls elaborate and /or provide more info /links on the same? Thanks a ton in advance for your help

Comment: Just ignore the PCI host controller outbound mapping. It's just for address routing among peripheral modules, not related to the topic we are discussing.